# Need help to backup cellphone - I need output power 5V 1A from AA batteries

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, diy

How do I get 5V 1A for my backup battery for my cellphone from four AA batteries? (Each battery is 1.5V 2500mAh.)

1. Is it better to use a 7805 to regulate from 6V to 5V 1A to power my cellphone? Here's a schematic diagram I found:

[image]

2. Or should I use this HT7750A from 2 AA batteries to 5V? Here's the schematic diagram:

[image]

Comment: a step up converter design is the most efficient for your purpose. Both chips you provided are rated for 200-300mA, so you'll need to look for a different one.

Comment: The 7805 requires ***atleast*** 7V for proper 5V output regulation.

Comment: then what should i do to get the output power of 5v 1A to recharge my cellphone @Passerby

Comment: or this step up using MAX756 from 1 AA batt to 5v(i dont know what is the ampere :( )
here's the schematic diagram ]http://i57.tinypic.com/wi62za.png
pls help me with these diagram i dont know the other meaning
can i put 2 AA batteries?

i need an output of 5v 1A for fast charging @DThought

Comment: The output voltage from AA batteries drops fast at a current of 1A.

Comment: I and everybody else use a PowerBank to remotely charge my phone. Then I charge the PowerBank from a USB after it has charged my phone 6 times.

Answer (score 1):

The folks over at adafruit has a great tutorial on how to do just this

https://learn.adafruit.com/minty-boost

It is tried and tested on both android and iphone.

Using a linear regulator is not practical due to power wasted. A boost regulator is what is going to give you the max efficiency from the batteries.

Comment: this boost regulator using MAX756 from 1 AA batt to 5v(i dont know what is the ampere :( )
here's the schematic diagram [IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/wi62za.png[/IMG][![enter image description here][3]][3]
pls help me with these diagram i dont know the other meaning
can i put 2 AA batteries? @evolutionizer

Comment: but in the link he/she stated the output power is 5v and 500mah.. i was thingking that is for slow charge but i want recharge my cellphone fast using 5v and 1A @evolutionizer

Comment: That is limited by the IC, have a look at http://www.linear.com/parametric/Micropower_Boost#!cols_1040,2167,1367,1035,1036,1033,1032,1034!s_1035,0!gtd_!1035_%3E=0.85 and http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3528

Comment: The reason a linear regulator is not suitable is not efficiency, per se. The problem is that 4 alkaline cells in series will very quickly drop below 5V during discharge. The efficiency of a linear regulator is pretty good when Vin and Vout are close together.

Comment: I think you can power the ada-fruit minty-boost with 4AA batteries in series. This will give you a lot more than 500 mA. You might need to change a couple of components. Mainly, the Schottky diode (need higher current) and the input capacitor (need higher voltage rating). You can probably still use the minty-boost circuit board, although if the substitute components are larger, they may not fit inside the can. But that is OK, because you can't fit 4AA batteries in there either.

Comment: @mkeith the 500mA limitation is from the booster IC, yes the other components will also have to be rated appropriately but it's primarily the boost ic

Comment: so instead of 1302ic of minty-boost i will replace this LTC3528? to become 5v 1A output power? @evolutionizer

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8bp0im this is the schematic of minty boost @evolutionizer

Comment: @KennyTan In a nutshell yes, have a thorough look at the datasheet for proper info on using it. Will prevent any surprises later on

Comment: okay sir/maam thanks a lot for big help. i might be able to find this LTC3528 ic tommorow for my project DIY powerbank for my android phone @evolutionizer

Comment: @evolutionizer, I don't think I am wrong. Read the datasheet for the LT1302. When input voltage is higher, it can support higher output current. There is a graph showing Vout vs Iout when Vin is 4V. The graph goes up to 1A. Also, there is a graph showing max power vs input Voltage. It shows over 6W at 4V Vin. So the 500 mA limitation is not a hard limit. If you power it with 4AA batteries, it will deliver a lot more than 500 mA.

Comment: @mkeith I just got a better look at the datasheet, yes you are right